# How to remove string between parentheses

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I try to find the right expression to remove some strings in my Google Spreadsheet. I have lot of cells based on this model :

```
15.01 km2 (5.80 sq mi)
```

I want to remove all the text from `km2` for this result: `15.01`.

I've tried LEFT function but it cannot be based on a text. I guess it can be achieved using REGEXEXTRACT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For:

> "how to remove string between parenthesis"

Select the relevant cells and try Find:

```
\(.+\)
```

Replace with nothing with Search Search using regular expressions.

The parentheses need escaping (with `\`), `.` refers to any character and `+` any number of times.

For:

> "remove all the text from `km2` for this result: `15.01`"

Try Find:

```
\s.+
```

(as above), where `\s` is space.

Comment: Thank you for theses informations! So, im using : =REGEXREPLACE(CellName;"\s.+";"")